# How to change the class using Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

In my app i have four tabs, on click of one tab a class name will be added, By using that class name CSS are written. I have implemented the same in jquery by adding the class on Tab click, but in angular I am finding it difficult, someone help me out in this.

**HTML**

```
     <div id="main-tabs">
          <div class="name-des">
            <h4>Hi Divya</h4>
            <p>As an admin what would you like to do today? </p>
          </div>
          <div class="allwindows " ng-style="updateMargin">
           <a href="#addpfm" class="viewawards">
            <p>Add PFM/GI</p>
            </a> 
            <a href="#/awards" class="addawards">
            <p>Manage Awards</p>
            </a> 
            <a  href="#/nomination" class="nomination">
            <p>Manage Nomination <br/>
              Window</p>
            </a> <a href="#/report" class="report">
            <p>Report</p>
            </a> 
            </div>

  <div ng-view class="reveal-animation animate-show"></div>
   </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 app.controller('nominationController', function($scope) {
    changeTabs("yellow");
 });

  app.controller('awardsController',function($scope){
  changeTabs("green");
  });

   app.controller('reportController',function($scope){
    changeTabs("red");  
  });
  app.controller('addpfmController',function($scope){
  changeTabs("blue");   
   });
  app.controller('reportController',function($scope){
  changeTabs("red");    
  });

 function changeTabs(className){
  $("#main-tabs").attr("class", className);
  $('.name-des').hide( 3000 );
  }
```

Here is the function written in jquery. I need to replace this code with angular code, Someone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please create fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this many controllers for this. A single controller is enough to handle this interaction.

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.className = "yellow"; // if you need a default
}
```

Then, in the view, you use `ng-class` to set the class and `ng-click` to set the className:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="className">
  <div class="name-des">
    <h4>Hi Divya</h4>
    <p>As an admin what would you like to do today?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="allwindows " ng-style="updateMargin">
    <a href="#addpfm" class="viewawards" ng-click="className = 'blue'">
      <p>Add PFM/GI</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#/awards" class="addawards" ng-click="className = 'green'">
      <p>Manage Awards</p>
    </a>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when we set `className='blue'` is that going to set the class as `blue`?

Comment: @New Dev On clicking on that the class is adding but again clicking on another <a> tag, the class is getting appending. but actually if it is in "red" class then on click of another tab it should change to another color like "blue" br removing "red".

Comment: @manojistack, you are doing something wrong then. `ng-class="className"` will set the class to whatever `className` equals to - not append it

Comment: @New Dev No it has not solved so only dint give you up for your answer, or else regularly ill give up for when ever i got answer, sorry yaar.

Comment: @manojistack, this is working for me - http://plnkr.co/edit/OotO3BRtuUZMcg7FIrKR?p=preview. tell me where you have the problem

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood You can use `ng-click`

```
<div id="main-tabs" ng-controller="myController">
      <div class="name-des">
        <h4>Hi Divya</h4>
        <p>As an admin what would you like to do today? </p>
      </div>
      <div class="allwindows " ng-style="updateMargin">
       <a href="#addpfm" ng-click="changeTabs('yourColor')" class="viewawards">
        <p>Add PFM/GI</p>
        </a> 
        <a href="#/awards" ng-click="changeTabs('yourColor')" class="addawards">
        <p>Manage Awards</p>
        </a> 
        <a  href="#/nomination" ng-click="changeTabs('yourColor')" class="nomination">
        <p>Manage Nomination <br/>
          Window</p>
        </a> <a href="#/report" ng-click="changeTabs('yourColor')" class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        </a> 
        </div>

 <div ng-view class="reveal-animation animate-show"></div>
 </div>
```

and in your controller you can write function like this

```
$scope.changeTabs= function (color){
   console.log(color);
   //your logic here
};
```

(*It will be easy you made a fiddle.*)